# Docker - PHP 7.2 FPM Alpine - Imagick

Tags: docker, php-fpm, php7, docker-compose, imagemagick

I'm using Docker image `php:7.2-fpm-alpine` as base image with following command to install Imagick:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache autoconf g++ imagemagick-dev libtool make pcre-dev \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && apk del autoconf g++ libtool make pcre-dev
```

Everything went fine with build and I have php7.2 with Imagick but it cannot be used because of following error:

```
UnableToOpenConfigureFile `coder.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/714
```

I'm trying to fix this for two hours. I tried with adding XML libraries without any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files you are missing are in the [`imagemagick`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/aarch64/imagemagick) package, which you also need to `apk add` explicitly. The dependencies for [`imagemagick-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/aarch64/imagemagick-dev) do not pull it in.